# What exactly does prepareForReplace () inserthelper android

Tags: android

I know that InsertHelper is deprecated but my app is so old used IntertHelper in so many places so I did not change those functions.

My query is what exactly prepareforReplace() function does,

```
            helper.prepareForReplace();
            helper.bind(userIdcColumn, dto.getUser_id());
            helper.bind(usernameColumn, dto.getUsername());
            helper.execute();
```

for ex: My table contains userid and username
the abovecode code I used to insert data, if already that userid present in my table it updates his data or it re-inserts the same userid?